# Can't run brain.js with json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, brain.js

Trying to load a network from JSON results in an the following error

> Error: Sizes must be set before initializing.

**My js code:**

```
let brain = require('brain.js');
let fs = require('fs');
let fileContent = fs.readFileSync("network.j
son", "utf8");
const net = new brain.NeuralNetwork();
console.log(fileContent);
net.fromJSON(fileContent);
console.log(net.run([1,0]));
```

If I just ask to output json to the console, then everything works, if I create in the code

```
let json = {...};
```

everything works, but when I try to load from a Json file, an error appears
[image: console image]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fs.readFileSync returns a string according to  https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options

> fs.readFileSync(path[, options])#
>
> **path** string | Buffer | URL | integer filename or file descriptor
>
> **options** Object | string
>
> **encoding** string | null Default: null
>
> **Returns: string | Buffer**

thus, you need to pass your `fileContent` to `JSON.parse` to parse your JSON string, the result from `fs.readFileSync`, to JavaScript value or object before using `net.fromJSON` eg.

```js
let fileContent = fs.readFileSync("network.json", "utf8");
let fileContentJSON = JSON.parse(fileContent);
const net = new brain.NeuralNetwork();

net.fromJSON(fileContentJSON);
```

Comment: `JSON.parse` changes a string of JSON into a JavaScript object (or array or whatever the JSON represents).

Comment: All he is saying is that fromJSON needs an object, which is correct.  I'm the maintainer of the library in question.